# Faster parsing of BigQuery JSON results

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I am building an API that uses BigQuery as the data source. We've done considerable work on data storage, partitioning and query optimizations, however, I am having some trouble with parsing the query result efficiently. In some cases for example, where there are 50+ large rows of JSON, I'm seeing parsing take 3 seconds or more, which on top of query execution and HTTP request/response is far from ideal.

Below is a simplified version of what I am doing using a public BigQuery dataset, my query is much more complex, however, the parsing is the same which is what I need some help with.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import json

sql = """
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) FROM (
SELECT * FROM
`bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories`
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
) as t
"""

client = bigquery.Client()
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
query_job = client.query(sql,job_config=job_config)
results = query_job.result()

# Begin parsing results to valid
# JSON for API response
json_response = '['
i = 0
for row in results:
    json_response = json_response + row[0]
    if i != total_rows:
        json_response = json_response + ","
    i += 1

json_response = json_response + ']'    

print(json_response)
```

I've tried to follow some of the performance tips as listed [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) but keep hitting errors I can't get past.

Note: i'm new to Python having coded in Ruby for the last few years.

**Edit:**
I've tried a few alternative ways of building the JSON response and in reaction to Micah's comment, I ran some profiling, here's the outcome.

Version 1 (original as above)

```
json_response = '['
i = 0
for row in results:
    json_response = json_response + row[0]
    if i != total_rows:
        json_response = json_response + ","
    i += 1

json_response = json_response + ']'
```

Average time to build response = 1.7962s

Version 2

```
json_list = [ json.loads(row[0]) for row in results]
json_response = json.dumps(json_list)
```

Average time to build response = 2.4789s

I would guess the json.loads and json.dumps adds latency here.

Version 3 (based on Micah's suggestion)

```
a = [row[0] for row in results]
json_response = ",".join(a)
```

Average time to build response = 1.9623s

I much prefer the code for V2&3 but V1 is still the quickest approach despite being slow.

Comment: Where does the large JSON data come from? Is it from certain column storing JSON or is it as your sample query, you formed a JSON to be returned from BigQuery. The solution can be different.

Comment: It's from the later / second option. The table has many columns and using the TO_JSON_STRING() command JSON rows are returned.

Comment: It might help to do more profiling.  How long does `a =[row[0] for row in results]` take?  How long does `",".join(a)` take?  In either case Join should be faster then your current loop.

Comment: I've made some edits above where i've profiled two new approaches

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it as follows:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import json


# BigQuery Setup and Query
project_name = 'my_project'
client = bigquery.Client(project=project_name)
query = 'select to_json_string(t) as my_stuff from schema.dataset'

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.use_query_cache = False
query_job = client.query(query, job_config = job_config)

results = query_job.result()

json_list = []

for row in results:
    json_list.append(row.my_stuff)

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_list,f)
```

If you need the field names, or multiple fields, use `to_json_string(struct(t))` or `to_json_string(struct(a,b,c) as values))`